# Jquery Datatable stop event Onclick of Imagebutton

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, datatables

i have an asp Repeater with a table:

```
<td>
   <asp:ImageButton ID="bt_elimina_urgentes" OnClick="bt_elimina_urgentes_Click1" CommandArgument='<%# 
      DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "etiqueta") %>'
      ImageUrl="../../Logistica/Carretillas/no.png" runat="server" />&nbsp;&nbsp;                                                           
 </td>
```

then, on click the imageButton, the tr is deleted with jquery datatables:

```
$('#grilla').on('click', 'input', function () {               
                var pageParamTable = $('#grilla').DataTable();
                var tableRow = pageParamTable.row($(this).parents('tr'));
                pageParamTable.row(tableRow).remove().draw();
            });
```

The problem is that the event Onclick of imagebutton on codebehind not firing. If comment the line
`pageParamTable.row(tableRow).remove().draw();` works well.

Which is the problem?? how can I do it?

Comment: Are you removing the row the ImageButton is in before its event fires? If your ImageButton is updating some data in the backend that needs to be reflected in the datatable, then I would recommend getting rid of the `OnClick` event. Then in your javascript click event, make an ajax call to the `bt_elimina_urgentes_Click1` event, update your data, then on the return of the ajax call remove the row AFTER the data has been updated.

Comment: Yes, first fires jquery, therefore tr is deleted and the imageButton too. 
As you commented,I used Ajax call to a function code behind and works well. But if the table have a search filter, reset it. How can I avoid it??. Thanks¡¡¡

Comment: Finally I found the parameter  `"stateSave": true` .It's save  the page and search/filter via local storage.